# Calculating limit for Integral (Riemann Sum)

Tags: limits, exponentiation, fractions, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I am trying to solve one of the exercises my professor told us to try, just to understand how Integral calculations work using Riemann Sums instead of antiderivatives.

However, I got stuck as I do not know how to continue simplifying...

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n [(-1+ \frac{4i}{n})^3 + 1]\frac{4}{n}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [(-1+ \frac{4i}{n})^3 + 1]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n}[\sum_{i=1}^n (-1+ \frac{4i}{n})^3 + \sum_{i=1}^n 1]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n}[\sum_{i=1}^n (-1+ \frac{4i}{n})^3 + n]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n}[(-1+ \frac{4}{n})^3\sum_{i=1}^n (i^3) + n]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{n}[(-1+ \frac{4}{n})^3( \frac{n^2(n+1)}{4}) + n]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [(\frac{-4}{n}+ \frac{16}{n^3})^3( \frac{n^2(n+1)}{4}) + 4]$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [(\frac{-4}{n}+ \frac{16}{n^3})^3(\frac{n^4+2n^3+2n^2}{4}) + 4]$

This is where I got stuck. I have no idea what to do with the first parenthesis, especially because of the exponent 3...

Thank you for your help in advance. I am also ready to give explanation on my reasoning or calculations if needed.

Comment: Why do you want to "simplify" that sum? As it is , with the limit, it  equals  $\;\int_{-1}^3(x^3+1)dx\;$ ...

Comment: @donantonio The OP is using Riemann Sums to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\left(-1+\frac{4i}{n} \right)^3=-1+\frac{12i}{n} -\frac{48i^2}{n^2}+\frac{64i^3}{n^3}$$

Comment: Thank you! How did you find thst out?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$.